# Send email with embedded image without using wordeditor

Tags: c#, .net, image, sendmail, outlook-2007

I am having troubles sending email with embedded image. I tried some solutions using word editor but they can't solve my circumstances. I can't use SmtpClient becuase a client does not want it. He has exchange and needs to have sent email in sent folder.

I want send an email in html format with eg. image in header - logo and image in footer - sign.

I have and HTML template stored in database as string to provide more looks and purposes of an email. Specific data I insert using variables which are replaced in moment of sending.

Does anyone know how to add image stored in database to email into  without using mailitem.wordeditor and without need to display inspector? Let's assume the images are already on disc or can be a stream somehow used?

My application needs send in background without notify the user by another windows. Adding images using wordeditor needs to have inspector displayed. And even when I immediately close it, it blinks.

The second trouble is how to format HTMLBody property of mailitem, when it does not accept normal HTML but only their so-called html. Is it really needed to study their word html?

Firstly I used MailMessage and this template worked even with images and alternativeviews. Maybe exist some posibility to use MailMessage to send it via outlook, but I dont know it.

Does anoyne came accross with it?

```
    public void SendEmailViaOutlook()
    {
        //in template I mostly need to use table and css to divide email into blocks - header, content, footer

        String htmlTemplate = "<html>\n";
        htmlTemplate += "  <head>\n";
        htmlTemplate += "    <style type=\"text//css\">\n";
        htmlTemplate += "       #Header  {border-width: 1; border: solid; text-align: center}\n";
        htmlTemplate += "       #Content {border-width: 1; border: solid; text-align: center}\n";
        htmlTemplate += "       #Footer   {border-width: 1; border: solid; text-align: center}\n";
        htmlTemplate += "    </style>\n";
        htmlTemplate += "  </head>\n";
        htmlTemplate += "  <body>\n";
        htmlTemplate += "    <table>\n";
        htmlTemplate += "      <tr><td><img src=\"cid:companylogo\"/></td></tr>\n";
        htmlTemplate += "      <tr><td><div id=\"Header\">$HEADER$</div></td></tr>\n";
        htmlTemplate += "      <tr><td><div id=\"Contentr\">$CONTENT$</div></td></tr>\n";
        htmlTemplate += "      <tr><td><div id=\"Footer\">$FOOTER$</div></td></tr>\n";
        htmlTemplate += "      <tr><td><img src=\"cid:usersign\"/></td></tr>\n";
        htmlTemplate += "    </table>\n";
        htmlTemplate += "  </body>n";
        htmlTemplate += "</html>\n";

        //the code is simplified to demostrate problem
        //$CONTENT etc. will be replaced by another html from custom html wysiwyg editor

        try
        {
            Outlook.Application outlook = new Outlook.Application();
            Outlook._MailItem outLookMailMessage = outlook.CreateItem(Outlook.OlItemType.olMailItem) as Outlook._MailItem;
            outLookMailMessage.BodyFormat = Outlook.OlBodyFormat.olFormatHTML;

            /*

            here a I have problem to set the property - my template is not
            set and a blank email is sent - almost none html it takes except the example from msdn http://support.microsoft.com/kb/310262, are there some rules how to write it?

            */

            outLookMailMessage.HTMLBody = htmlTemplate;
            outLookMailMessage.Subject = this.Subject;

            outLookMailMessage.Recipients.Add("somenone@somewhere.com");

            /*
             here I woud need somehow link 2 images with cid companylogo and usersign
             */

            outLookMailMessage.Send();
            outLookMailMessage = null;
        }
        catch (System.Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: I think you just add it as an attachment, with the same name as the cid specified in the html body.

Comment: I tried but it shows only blank image

Comment: Are the files named "companylogo" and "usersign" like in the html body? Are the attachments called the same names as well? Could you update your question to the code you're tried with?

Comment: no they aren't, they are stored in database a companylogo is an alias fot the attachment, it does not have to be named this way

Comment: I renamed cid property to companylogo.jpg@embed a set attachment to:
                                    `attachment.PropertyAccessor.SetProperty("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x3712001E", name + ".jpg@EMBED");` and now it works

Comment: Glad to hear it - please post that as an answer and accept it, or accept one of the answers below if they provided what you needed. That way others know that the question is now resolved!

Comment: I can't I do not 15 reputation points for voting. But I answered the question.

Comment: I didn't mean vote for it - I meant accept it. Isn't there a tick option to the left hand side to mark it as the accepted answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Check this msdn thread on embedding an image](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/pl-PL/vsto/thread/6c063b27-7e8a-4963-ad5f-ce7e5ffb2c64)

Comment: Thanks, that offered me better view on problematics

Answer (score 2):

Here is the code for sending the image in oulook

```
Configuration config = System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager
    .OpenWebConfiguration(HttpContext.Request.ApplicationPath);
var settings = (System.Net.Configuration.MailSettingsSectionGroup)
    config.GetSectionGroup("system.net/mailSettings");
var smtp = settings.Smtp;
System.Net.Configuration.SmtpNetworkElement network = smtp.Network;
var outlookApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application();
var mailItem = (MailItem)outlookApp.CreateItem(OlItemType.olMailItem);
mailItem.To = network.TargetName;

Attachment attachment = mailItem.Attachments.Add
    ( "C://test.bmp"
    , OlAttachmentType.olEmbeddeditem
    , null
    , "test image"
    );

string imageCid = "test.bmp@123";

attachment.PropertyAccessor.SetProperty
    ( "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x3712001E"
    , imageCid
    );

mailItem.BodyFormat = OlBodyFormat.olFormatRichText;
mailItem.HTMLBody = String.Format
     ( "<body><img src=\"cid:{0}\"></body>"
     , imageCid
     );

mailItem.Importance = OlImportance.olImportanceNormal;
mailItem.Display(false);
```

---

```
<mailSettings>
      <smtp from="test@gmail.com">
        <network host="hostname" port="portrnumber" 
            userName="domain/username" password="password" 
            targetName="targetname@gmail.com"/>
      </smtp>
</mailSettings>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using [SmtpClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/system.net.mail.smtpclient%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) as shown  [here](http://blog.devexperience.net/en/12/Send_an_Email_in_CSharp_with_Inline_attachments.aspx)?

```
System.Net.Mail.Attachment inline = new System.Net.Mail.Attachment(@"imagepath\filename.png");
inline.ContentDisposition.Inline = true;
```

Comment: Yes, but I can't use SmtpClient because out customer does not permit smtp relaying

Comment: Yes, but Outlook running on the server will use his own Smtp Client to send emails, so you would have the same problem

Comment: In this case no, because customer's coupmuter's Outlooks uses Exchange, so my task is just submit to outlook, but thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

```
  public void SendEmailViaOutlook()
    {
        String htmlTemplate = "<html>\n";
        htmlTemplate += "  <head>\n";
        htmlTemplate += "    <style type=\"text//css\">\n";
        htmlTemplate += "       #Header  {border-width: 1; border: solid; text-align: center}\n";
        htmlTemplate += "       #Content {border-width: 1; border: solid; text-align: center}\n";
        htmlTemplate += "       #Footer   {border-width: 1; border: solid; text-align: center}\n";
        htmlTemplate += "    </style>\n";
        htmlTemplate += "  </head>\n";
        htmlTemplate += "  <body>\n";
        htmlTemplate += "    <table>\n";
        htmlTemplate += "      <tr><td><img src=\"cid:companylogo.jpg@embed\"/></td></tr>\n";
        htmlTemplate += "      <tr><td><div id=\"Header\">$HEADER$</div></td></tr>\n";
        htmlTemplate += "      <tr><td><div id=\"Contentr\">$CONTENT$</div></td></tr>\n";
        htmlTemplate += "      <tr><td><div id=\"Footer\">$FOOTER$</div></td></tr>\n";
        htmlTemplate += "      <tr><td><img src=\"cid:usersign.jpg@embed\"/></td></tr>\n";
        htmlTemplate += "    </table>\n";
        htmlTemplate += "  </body>n";
        htmlTemplate += "</html>\n";

        //the code is simplified to demostrate problem
        //$CONTENT etc. will be replaced by another html from custom html wysiwyg editor

        try
        {
            Outlook.Application outlook = new Outlook.Application();
            Outlook._MailItem outLookMailMessage = outlook.CreateItem(Outlook.OlItemType.olMailItem) as Outlook._MailItem;
            outLookMailMessage.BodyFormat = Outlook.OlBodyFormat.olFormatHTML;

            outLookMailMessage.HTMLBody = htmlTemplate;
            outLookMailMessage.Subject = this.Subject;

            outLookMailMessage.Recipients.Add("somenone@somewhere.com");


            path = ""; //set some path to folder with images

            Outlook.Attachment attachment1 = outLookMailMessage.Attachments.Add(path, Outlook.OlAttachmentType.olEmbeddeditem, null, "");                                 
            attachment1.PropertyAccessor.SetProperty("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x3712001E", "companylogo.jpg@EMBED");
            Outlook.Attachment attachment2 = outLookMailMessage.Attachments.Add(path, Outlook.OlAttachmentType.olEmbeddeditem, null, "");                                  
            attachment2.PropertyAccessor.SetProperty("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x3712001E", "usersign.jpg@EMBED");
            outLookMailMessage.Send();
            outLookMailMessage = null;
        }
        catch (System.Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```